# How do I allow users to remove their pictures from their user profile?

Tags: 7, users

Users on my recruitment website are able to upload profile pictures and CVs to their user profile. However, they aren't able to remove uploaded pictures and CVs or replace them with new files. What do I do to allow users to change their existing profile pictures as well as CVs?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As far as I see your case is not a standard one. Usually all fields in profile page are editable for users. Can you see in your site's permissions for authenticated users ( /admin/people/permissions ) do they have needed permissions? And please go to /admin/config/people/accounts/fields and give us configuration of your image and file fields.

Comment: Do you have modules for extended permission/access settings like [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) installed?

Comment: Hi Molot. Thanks for your speedy response. Permissions seem to all good, configuration is as follows: 1.Image: field type: image, widget: image. 2.CV:field type: file, widget: file. I do have field permissions installed @ЕлинЙ.@molot

Comment: Then you should check your permission settings for that field. There are 5 permissions for each field: "Create own, edit own, edit anyone's, view own, view anyone's". It seems that you didn't give the 'edit own value' permission to users.

Comment: Adrian, you only can ping one person with @ notation. So I wasn't notified. But it seems you got the right pointer. Can you update your question with new info? @ЕлинЙ. it looks like your last comment could (should?) be an answer :)

Comment: @Mołot Posted as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Field Permisions module, you should check the permission settings for that field. There are 5 permissions for each field: "Create own, edit own, edit anyone's, view own, view anyone's". It seems that you didn't give the 'edit own value' permission to users.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do as instructed. I have granted all relevant permissions on the /admin/people/permissions as well as field permissions module. Still no change. I even tried deactivating the field module, but still no change... My website is www.integraterecruitment.co.za you are welcome to browse and have a look. I am so lost and puzzled... @Елин Й.

Comment: I've created a dummy user account on your site. The permissions should be ok, since it shows the 'Remove' buttons for given fields. But if I click the 'Remove' button Firebug shows me a jQuery error: `TypeError: b.handleError is not a function` Do you have [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module installed? Or any other jQuery related or File related modules?

Comment: I've had a look to see if I have any jquery modules, but it doesn't seem like it... I have just downloaded the jQuery Update module to try and see if it works...

Comment: Youa are simply God Sent @Елин Й. downloaded the jQuery Update module and it works like a charm now!

Comment: Glad that your problem is solved. It seems any of other modules you have installed, requires a newer version of jQuery. Drupal ships with very old jQuery v1.4